# Why MySql Master-Master improves write performance?

Tags: mysql, database

One of the claims for master-master benefits is that it can be located in several physical sites and distributed across the network.
I know it sounds straightforward, since we can write to more than one node, but in fact, if we want strong consistency those nodes should now connect and lock each other. This adds more complexity and network calls than master-slave. In addition, we might face problems like 2 people are trying to buy the last item in the stock.
What am I missing?

Comment: Locking doesn't need as much network bandwidth as sending or receiving row data. So you get better throughput of the application data by using a closer server, at the expense of some locking overhead between the servers.

Comment: But it's not just the locking, it's also the writing of all the data to all the nodes (which is the same in master-slave). so If data is written on all nodes what is the benefit of the other master?

Comment: Replication happens in the background. So unless the client of the other master needs to read the same table you just wrote, there's no delay.

Comment: I think that this is the thing I don't understand. If I have master-mater (Node A & Node B ) with strong consistency then data should be written synchronously to both whether I'm written to A or B

Comment: I don't actually have any experience with multi-master. I've only used master-slave replication.

Comment: In master-slave are the replicas always synced asynchronously? can you set it to strong consistency?

Comment: I don't know. In our configuration it's asynchronous, and sometimes the slaves can be minutes or hours behind the master.

Answer (score 0):

Yes "it sounds straightforward", but when you get into the details and the unspoken requirements, it gets complex.

Multi-master is set up by simply having two Primaries treating each other as master-slave.  But...  It does not prevent the conflict you described.

If you want "strong consistency" in a multi-Primary write setup where you will be writing to all the Primaries, go with Galera.  It is delivered with MariaDB or can be added to MySQL.

Be aware that consistency across a network will be slowed down by the distance between nodes.  Galera has the overhead of one hop per `COMMIT`.  That effectively prevents two conflicting queries to both `COMMIT`.  But note:  the conflict is not reported to the application until returning from `COMMIT`.

3 nodes in the minimum for "single-point-of-failure" protection against one node crashing and letting the other two decide that they have a "quorum" and continue running as if there is no problem.  After fixing the dead node, the other nodes will help it get in sync before it starts taking more traffic.

I argue that the only use for Primary-Primary is that it allows for a quick failover.  It must be limited to writing to only one of them at a time (because of the case you mention).  And it is limited to only 2 servers (because more than 2 is *very* messy to recover from).

Your title alludes to "write performance".  But think about it.  Everything written to any Primary must *also* be written to every other Primary and Replica.  So, in any replication topology, there is only a small about of "write scaling".  This small benefit comes from the changing of rows on the Replica is often more straightforward than the extra overhead that comes with the initial write.  (Example:  An `UPDATE` that looks at a hundred rows, but changes only ten.  The Primary looked at all hundred, but the Replica only touched ten.)